# javafx: change style dynamically on pane

Tags: css, javafx, styles, stylesheet

I am trying to change the style of a pane when my mouse goes over it and change it back to normal when my mouse is outside the pane.

I can do something like that

```
pane.setStyle("");
```

However I want my css code to be in a css stylesheet and I was wondering if it's possible to create something like togglebutton

```
.togglebutton{
     -fx-background-color:red;
}

.togglebutton:selected{
     -fx-background-color:green;
}
```

Thus, each time I select my togglebutton, the style change automatically.

The question is : is it possible to create a parameter to act like the togglebutton. Something like:

css stylesheet

```
.mypane{
     //do something
}

.mypane:selected{
     // do something else
}
```

java code

```
public void mousedragAction(MouseEvent event){
     mypane.isSelected(true);
}

public void mouseexit(MouseEvent event){
     mypane.isSelected(false);
}
```

Thank you very much for any help, or any other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is already implemented with the [`hover` pseudoclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node). So you can just do

```css
.myPane {
    /* do something */
}
.myPane:hover {
    /* do something else */
}
```

In general, though it's not necessary in this case, you can define arbitrary CSS pseudoclasses (which will work like `selected` and `hover`). To reproduce the hover functionality, for example, you can do:

```
PseudoClass moveOver = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("mouse-over");
Pane myPane = new Pane();
myPane.getStyleClass().add("my-pane");
myPane.setOnMouseEntered(e -> myPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(mouseOver, true));
myPane.setOnMouseExited(e -> myPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(mouseOver, false));
```

and then you can use the following CSS:

```css
.my-pane {
    -fx-background-color: white ;
}
.my-pane:mouse-over {
    -fx-background-color: yellow ;
}
```

Note the pseudoclass name in the CSS (`:mouse-over`) matches the string passed to the `getPseudoClass` method (`PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("mouse-over")`), and can be any string that is valid to use as a CSS identifier.

Comment: Another `PseudoClass` example [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/846eb9ff72bd66fdd955)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much